# Cómo buscar y remplazar en script de Sql Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, ssms

necessito remplazar una las cadenas de tipo `20-04-1992` por `20/04/1992`
Es decir que me reeemplace los separadores `-` por `/` en todas las fechas que encuentre.

Con `....-..-..` localiza los que cumplen el criterio, pero no se cómo remplazar sólo el carácter `-`

Muchas gracias

Comment: Y si editas el script T-SQL en, digamos, notepad++ y reemplazas lo que estás buscando con una expresión regular?

Comment: Ya lo he provado, tal y como decía en mi comentario, se localizar las cadenas que cumplan el patron, pero no se como decirle que de la cadena, solo me sustituya el caracter '-' respetando los digitos de la fecha

Comment: Hay razón para ese cambio?, Solo quieres saber como buscar y sustituir? , O esc que quieres que ese sea el formato en la BBDD?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes abrir el archivo en, digamos, notepad++, usar la opción **Reemplazar** y seleccionar la el radiobutton Regular expression. Luego, usar lo siguiente:

- Buscar: `(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})`
- Reemplazar por: `$1/$2/$3`

Estás buscando una expresión que tenga tres grupos, cada uno con dos caracteres numéricos separados por guiones, y la estás reemplazando por el contenido de los tres grupos (que se crean con los paréntesis), separados por *slash*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la combinación de teclas Ctrl + H y te aparecera el siguiente recuadro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el primer campo de texto ingresa el texto a buscar y en el siguiente el texto por el cual se va a reemplazar. Espero te sea de ayuda